# Can I `ls` all files in a directory from "1", "2",...,"9", "10", "11", ..., "20", "21", ...?

Tags: ls

I have a directory with files named "1", "2",...,"9", "10", "11", ..., "20", "21", ... inside.

Can I list them in the order of "1", "2",...,"9", "10", "11", ..., "20", "21", ...?

I have tried `ls -ls`. It doesn't list the files that way, but instead "1", "10", "11", ..., "19", "2", "20", "21", ....
I guess a feature like that will be helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU `ls` (as found on most Linux distributions), you can use `ls -v`, where `-v`, from the `man` page

> ```
>  -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
> ```

Answer (score 1):

GNU `ls -v` has already been mentioned, but for other commands, if your shell is `zsh`, you can affect the order wildcards are expanded with globbing qualifiers.

For instance:

```
printf '%s\n' *(om)
```

Would list the files sorted by <kbd>m</kbd>odification time (from the newest to the oldest), `*(Om)` to reverse the sort order (from the oldest to the newest).

`*(n)` would sort the files numerically. So if your `ls` is not the GNU `ls`, you could still do:

```
ls -fdl -- *(n)
```

To get the list numerically sorted.